# How can we implement Google Map in AutoScrollViewPager?

Tags: android

I don't have much experience in Android and I am facing an issue related to Google map and **AutoScrollViewPager**. My requirement is like I want to display some screens and each screen has different data and different location on map.

All screens are swipable and swipes automatically too, so I used **AutoScrollViewPager** for this. In **AutoScrollViewPager**, I used **AutoScrollViewPagerAdapter** to add data on screens. Now I want different map on each screen which shows different locations for different screen.

I used SupportMapFragment, MapView for this but both does not allow me create different maps for each screen in adapter. Also Adapter does not have any method related to lifecycle of fragment or activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you would be needing fully functional maps in the ViewPaper. If you are just looking to show the location on the map, you can simply use images for that. Use the **[Google Static Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/)** to get the images for the locations and show them in the ViewPager.